# R - passing variables to ddply, refering to columns by name or index, quick syntax problem

Tags: r, plyr

I am aware there treads out there for similar problems, but after hours of trying I couldn't run my script.
I would like run ddply within a custom function, but would like to pass the column names as variables to it.

I have tried referencing either with the index of the column or its string name, but no luck

```
colnum2 <- which(colnames(z) == "TAZ")
colnum2 <- "TAZ"
```

```
output <- ddply(df, .(AColumnNameThatIsFixed), summarise, 
             ANewColInSummary = sum(.(colnum2) ==  0))
```

*This does not run*

```
hey <- ddply(z, .(AColumnNameThatIsFixed), summarise, 
                ANewColInSummary = sum(z[[colnum2]] ==  0))
```

*This does not give the right result as it does not evaluate per row.*

The data and summary is obviously more complex but this shows the fundamental problem.

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example using `dput` along with expected output ? Also since `plyr` is [retired](https://github.com/hadley/plyr) you should switch to `dplyr` now which gives much better flexibility.

Comment: Cheers, will try ddply!